# How to implement test set in classification Model for Prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, natural-language

I have 100 documents which I have converted to Dataframe with the target variable.

In supervised learning we need a target variable or label,
Y = f(x)
So, I created a training set for with my contents of documents as X and labeled them as Y. Where as I have also prepared a test set. But According to rules the test set should not have a Y variable as the test set is considered as wild data for model evaluation.

My question is How do I use the test set in my existing classification model that I have prepared? I am confused.

Comment: Test set should have target variable; otherwise how would you calculate the generalization capability?

Comment: @discipulus I am getting it. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You model your data on training set, and evaluate the model on test set. Test set not having the target is a matter of implementation. In general, test set is created from original training samples to identify the generalization capability or for model selection. I'd recommend you to read some basics of cross-validation or post your pseudo codes here.